# This is an estimation in a paper I read recently, but I could’t get through.

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that $$\min \{1, (n\theta)^{-d/p-1/2}(\pi-\theta)^{-1/2} \}\le C (n\theta)^{-d/p}$$

Where $C$ is a constant depends only on $d$ and $p$.

I tried to prove this by discussion $(n\theta)^{-d/p-1/2}(\pi-\theta)^{-1/2}\le 1$ and $(n\theta)^{-d/p-1/2}(\pi-\theta)^{-1/2}\ge 1 $. But I don’t know how to figure out the range of $\theta$ in both cases.

Comment: This should be right for $\theta \in [0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider

$$\min \{(n\theta)^{d/p}, (n\theta)^{-1/2}(\pi-\theta)^{-1/2} \}\le C$$

which can be written

$$\theta\le\frac{C^{p/d}}n\lor \theta(\pi-\theta)\ge\frac1{nC^2}.$$

The claim must be true because $0<\theta<\pi$ so that the function on the left is bounded.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I still can not see why this formula is true for $0\leq\theta\leq \pi$

Comment: @YeliNiu: hem, a bounded function is... bounded.

Comment: In my understanding, your formula $$\theta\le\frac{C^{p/d}}n\lor \theta(\pi-\theta)\ge\frac1{nC^2}.$$ means $$\{\theta\le\frac{C^{p/d}}n\}\bigcup\{ \theta(\pi-\theta)\ge\frac1{nC^2}\}$$ which equals to $$\{\theta\le\frac{C^{p/d}}n\}\bigcup [\frac{\pi-\sqrt(\pi^2-4/nC^2)}2, \frac{\pi+\sqrt(\pi^2-4/nC^2)}2]$$ But $[0,\pi]$ does not contained in this interval